# array creation from recursion

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a array 'featureList' from which I need to create another array 'newArray' which will have data as For example for id 5 new array would be ['MotherBoard','Antenna','Receiver'] 
where Receiver is from current ID, Antenna is from parentID of Receiver and MotherBoard is from parentID of Antenna.

what would be the best recursion to achieve the new array?

Currently I am not achieving this with below code.

```
const newArray: string[] = [];
    for (const feature of featureList) {
      if (feature.id === this.featureId) {
        newArray.push(feature.name);
        if (feature.parentFeatureId) {
          for (const parentFeature of featureList) {
            if (parentFeature.id === feature.parentFeatureId) {
              newArray.push(parentFeature.name);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }


  var featureList = [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "MotherBoard",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": null
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Power Supply",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Antenna",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Transmitter",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Receiver",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Storage",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": null
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Calibration State",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "User Profile mgm",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "HW State mgm",
        "projectId": 1,
        "parentFeatureId": 6
      }
    ]
```

Comment: why do you want recursion?

Comment: where is `this.featureId` coming from, or what do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a recursive function:

```
var getParentsArray = function(id){
  var curr = featureList.find(el=>el.id===id);
    if (curr && curr.parentFeatureId)
      return [...getParentsArray(curr.parentFeatureId), curr.name]
    else if (curr)
      return [curr.name];
    else
      return [];
};
```

The function starts with your chosen id, finds the object with that id in `featureList` and returns an array of the parents names followed by the name of the object.
The parents names are recursively determined by calling the function with parentFeatureId

See https://jsfiddle.net/ps1ks89a/16/ for more.

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, you could use an recursive approach by respecting the actual index and by keeping visited feature names.

If an target item is found, the collected names list is returned.

This approach uses a sorted list, where the parents comes before there children.

```js
function getFeatures(id, array, parent = null, index = 0, features = []) {
    var temp;
    while (index < array.length) {
        if (array[index].parentFeatureId !== parent) {
            index++;
            continue;
        }
        if (array[index].id === id) {
            return features.concat(array[index].name);
        }
        temp = getFeatures(id, array, array[index].id, index + 1, features.concat(array[index].name));
        if (temp) {
            return temp;
        }
        index++;
    }
}

var featureList = [{ id: 1, name: "MotherBoard", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: null }, { id: 2, name: "Power Supply", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: 1 }, { id: 3, name: "Antenna", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: 1 }, { id: 4, name: "Transmitter", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: 3 }, { id: 5, name: "Receiver", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: 3 }, { id: 6, name: "Storage", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: null }, { id: 7, name: "Calibration State", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: 6 }, { id: 8, name: "User Profile mgm", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: 6 }, { id: 9, name: "HW State mgm", projectId: 1, parentFeatureId: 6 }]

console.log(getFeatures(5, featureList));
```